# Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type table

Tags: arrays, matlab, text

I have a .txt (220 rows * 12 cols, first row text, rest of the file is decimal numbers) file, first I converted it to a table:
`T = readtable('xxx.txt','Delimiter','\t')`   and then saved T to .mat form.

Then I ran these codes:

```
>> load T.mat
>> col=0;
raa=0.05;
d=0;
c=0;
n=0;
w=0;
b=0;
data4=zeros(220,10);



for col=3:12

for i=1:220
     b=0;
     c=0;

for j=1:220
     if i~=j
           d=sqrt((T(i,1)-T(j,1))^2+(T(i,2)-T(j,2))^2);
            if d<30              
            c=(1/(d^2))*T(j,col);
            b=b+c;
           else
           end

    end
  end

x=T(i,col) - (raa * b);
n=i;

data4(i,col)= x;
  data4(i,1)=n;

   end

    %   dlmwrite('trash.txt',data4,'\t')
   dlmwrite('T-100spreg2-raa05.txt',data4,'\t')    
  end
```

I got an error message:

> Error: undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type table.

My questions are:

1. why when I checked the size of T I got ans=1    1, why not ans=220   12?
2. why I got this error message?
3. If I shouldn't use table T directly in the code, then I need to convert it to an array. I used A=table2array('T') and got:
   Error: Cell contents reference from a non cell array object 
   Error in table2array (line 27) a = t{:,:};
   Could it be I did something wrong from the first step i.e. convert .txt to table (thus I got ans=1  1 but not 220 12)?

Comment: It would be easier to figure out the errors if this was a reproducible example. Could you include the creation of a dummy table instead of just the load statement?

Comment: Why use a table at all? I would think a matrix would be a lot simpler. You should be able to directly read the file into a matrix rather than a table.

Comment: As @DavidK mentions, it may indeed not be neccesary to use a table. Have a look at `doc dlmread`.

Comment: @DavidK As long as I use dlmred, I got an error message to say it is problematic when reading numbers==>x y DEM asp grad DAI2 HI VI SLI2 Yield DAI1 SLI1\n. This is the first row of my .txt file.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting an error. Try `fscanf` and `textscan` as well. I would just skip the first row and start on the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, but it should explain why you got the error when trying to use `table2array`.

The input of the relevant function should not be the name of the table, but rather the table itself.
As such you should replace:

```
A=table2array('T')
```

by

```
A=table2array(T)
```

Perhaps this is enough to help you on your way and figure out the other issues as well.

Comment: It worked(A=table2array(T), A =1.0e+06 *). But the output looks weird. For example, in the txt file, the data in the second row are:1498704 6699085 109.079 27.26 0.06 0.14 173.498 0.627 0.459 24.366 34.116 11.325.  Then in the array A, these data became: 1.498704000000000   6.699085000000000   0.000109079000000   0.000027260000000   0.000000060000000   0.000000140000000   0.000173498000000   0.000000627000000   0.000000459000000   0.000024366000000   0.000034116000000   0.000011325000000. Another question, shall I use array A instead of table T in my coad?

Comment: Yeah OK, I used A instead of T in my coad,and it returns a file called A-100spreg2-raa05.txt(as indicated in the last stance in the coad). When I changed raa value to e.g. 0.01 then I got  A-100spreg2-raa01.txt. Thanks a lot for helping me, now I just gonna try different raa values and move on to the next step.

Comment: @ZhangYaoJiayin Just to reply to your first comment, if you have a large number in your vector/array, for example `v = [50000000 6 0.07]` matlab will use the scientific notation. It may look like it now says `[5.0000    0.0000    0.0000]` but in fact it says `1.0e+07 *[5.0000    0.0000    0.0000]` so in fact the magnitude (and precision) are not lost.

Comment: I changed raa value to 0:0.01:1(instead of raa=0.01, raa=0.02...and run the coad for several times), then it returns Error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @ZhangYaoJiayin That is a completely different question, as such I recommend the following: 1. Figure out where exactly it goes wrong by running the code with `dbstop if error`. If you can't find a solution after that, create a minimal code fragment with which people can recreate the problem. You can then use this to ask a new question.